# How was the Masoretic Text of the Hebrew Bible produced?

Tags: christianity, bible, judaism

I have recently been reading about verses in the New Testament that have been claimed by Jewish Scholars (ex. Rabbi Tovia Singer) to be corruptions of the real Hebrew old testament.  In most cases, the argument is that the writers of the New Testament exclusively quoted from the Septuagint which used Greek translations of Hebrew terms that were not really the best translations of the Hebrew terms.  For example, the Septuagint says "A virgin shall conceive..." but modern Jewish scholars claim that the original Hebrew used the term "maiden" which did not necessarily mean Virgin.  Singer also claims that the Septuagint only included the Pentateuch at the time that the New Testament is believed to have been written (circa late first century C.E.).

The Jews today regard the [Masoretic text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text) as the true Hebrew bible. The Masoretic text was produced  during the middle ages between 600 C.E. and about 1000 C.E.  I have read that the Masoretic text is regarded by historians as an "very" accurate representation of the ancient Hebrew Old Testament BECAUSE it is very consistent with the Septuagint and the Dead Sea Scrolls.  This suggests to me the the Masoretic text is not necessarily closer to the ancient Hebrew bible than the Septuagint or the Dead Sea scrolls which both have language that is more in line with the putative prophetic fulfillments in the New Testament than the Masoretic Text is.

So, exactly how was the Masoretic text produced?  What original documents were used as sources to produce it?  Was the Septuagint used?  Was oral Talmudic teachings and oral tradition used?  Were there any ancient pieces of the Old Testament from before the first century C.E. that were used to help develop the Masoretic text?  Most specifically, is there a good reason to believe that the Masoretic text was a better representation of the ancient Hebrew bible that existed prior to the Septuagint?  Just because it was written in Hebrew doesn't seem to justify elevating its accuracy, it seems to me we would need other reasons that give it continuity with the ancient Old Testament.  Is there any evidence or reason to believe that the Masoretic Text used translations of certain words that were knowingly less consistent with the quotes from the New Testament as a way of downplaying possible prophetic interpretations?  Most simply: How was the Masoretic text produced and what makes us think it was a very accurate representation of the ancient Old Testament other than it's consistency with the Septuagint and Dead Seas Scrolls?

Comment: Your last paragraph has eight (related) questions, which one would you like answered?

Comment: I've edited the title to clarify the question, if I'm misunderstood, please edit to ask the right question - but clearer the question, the more likely you are to get an answer.  Might also be useful to document the research you've already done, so that we don't repeat it.  Does [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text#Fixing_of_the_text) answer the question, and if not, why not?

Comment: Too many questions in one post. As is, it seems answered with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text ? Please focus this down or split it into multiple distinct question posts. Preferably, each with documentation of your prior research into this.